# Taiwan Visa for Pakistani

Tags: visas, pakistani-citizens, taiwan

I am a Pakistani, plan to visit South Korea in third week of Nov'19. From there I want to visit Taiwan for business purpose. I want to know can I apply and get Taiwan visa from South Korea. If yes, please send me the contact information.

Answer (score 1):

Taiwan doesn’t have an embassy in Pakistan, so you have to apply at an overseas embassy anyways.

Pakistan citizens aren’t eligible for the e-Visa so you have to apply for a visa in the embassy of Taiwan in South Korea bringing all your supporting documents with you.

As for the requirements of the visa, you'll find them all listed [here](https://www.boca.gov.tw/content.asp?mp=2&CuItem=1900) or [here](http://www.boca.gov.tw/ct.asp?xItem=1422&ctNode=777&mp=2). You'll need:

> - A passport valid for at least six months;
> - A duly completed application form with two photos taken within the past six months;
> - An outbound airline ticket or verifiable proof of purchase of steamship ticket ;
> - Documents verifying the purpose of visit;
> - Other relevant documents.
> - A visa fee of 50 or 100USD (single or multiple-entry)